# near "AS": syntax error (code 1) Error in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

I am getting following error when trying to update matching row using whereClause :

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AS": syntax error (code 1): , 
while compiling: 
UPDATE messages SET message=? WHERE (user_id = ? ) AND (message = ? ) AND (time = ? AS long) AND (chat_with_user_id = ? ) AND (from_me = ? AS integer ) AND (user_full_name = ? )
```

And code I am using is
:

```
int fromMeInt = 0;
if (fromMe) {
    fromMeInt = 1;
}

ContentValues dataToInsert = new ContentValues();
dataToInsert.put(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MESSAGE, urlFileName);

String userId ="("+ SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_USER_ID+" = ? )";
String message ="("+ SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MESSAGE+" = ? )";
String time = "("+SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TIME_STAMP+" = ? AS long)";
String chatWithId ="("+ SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CHAT_WITH_USER_ID+" = ? )";
String fromMeS = "("+SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_FROM_ME+" = ? AS integer )";
String UserNamee = "("+SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_USER_NAME+" = ? )";

String where = userId +" AND "+ message +" AND "+ time +" AND "+ chatWithId +" AND "+ fromMeS +" AND "+ UserNamee;
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(myUserId),
        String.valueOf(message),
        String.valueOf(timeStamp),
        String.valueOf(chatWithUserId),
        String.valueOf(fromMeInt),
        String.valueOf(UserName)};

int count = database.update(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_MESSAGES, dataToInsert, where, whereArgs);
Lg.info(TAG, "updateMessage updated: " + count);
Lg.info(TAG, "updateMessage where: " + where);
```

Any suggestion would be helpful, Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I know why my question is marked by -ve mark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the data type, you would have to use the [CAST expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr):

```
UPDATE messages
SET message = ?
WHERE user_id = ?
  AND message = ?
  AND time = CAST(? AS long)
  AND chat_with_user_id = ?
  AND from_me = CAST(? AS integer)
  AND user_full_name = ?;
```